# WEB API 2 : multiple calls to RegisterExternal creates multiple users

Tags: c#, oauth, asp.net-web-api2

I am using the out of the box AccountController to implement oauth through Facebook for my API

A new user calls:

```
GET api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl=%2F&generateState=true
```

and after redirecting and logging into Facebook they get a token that they use for registration (**out of the box code bellow**)

```
    // POST api/Account/RegisterExternal
    [OverrideAuthentication]
    [HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]
    [Route("RegisterExternal")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> RegisterExternal(RegisterExternalBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        ExternalLoginData externalLogin = ExternalLoginData.FromIdentity(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);

        if (externalLogin == null)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }

        IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser
        {
            UserName = model.UserName
        };
        user.Logins.Add(new IdentityUserLogin
        {
            LoginProvider = externalLogin.LoginProvider,
            ProviderKey = externalLogin.ProviderKey
        });
        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
        IHttpActionResult errorResult = GetErrorResult(result);

        if (errorResult != null)
        {
            return errorResult;
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

When I call RegisterExternal multiple times with a new user name (RegisterExternalBindingModel) but the same bearer token I end up creating multiple new users (only the first of which will be valid). Is there a standard way to prevent user from creating multiple redundant accounts?

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the data in the model but are you logged in under different accounts with external identity providers as well?

You could check for the existence of a user with the given username before going ahead and creating it. You should be doing this anyway?

Comment: i'm using the same one token as was given back from Facebook, but i'm changing up up the model (which is really just the user name). I can keep calling RegisterExternal since the token is still registered.

Comment: Why would you be creating different user accounts and linking them to the same external provider accounts though? Does .Net Identity allow that?

Comment: I don't intend to do it, the fear is other people messing with it. I'm rewriting the RegisterExternal anyways so I'll accommodate for that, was curious how other people were handling it

Comment: Not sure what you mean about other people messing with it. The code above works if you use it the way it's meant to be used. I added a check to see if the user already exists and if they do, I transfer them to the login flow rather than the register flow

Comment: Thanks for all your help John, I guess this is a redundant question. I'm rewriting this to not require a UserName anyways (don't need usernames) so its not going to be a security issue for me anyways. On another topic do you know how from RegisterExternal I can access the users Facebook data (first name, last name ext) I've open another question here: [access facebook data question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28653773/web-api-2-get-profile-data-during-oauth-registerexternal-facebook)